# Does system time tick on Arduino?

Tags: time, arduino, embedded

After setting system time via a call to a real-time-clock (RTC), repeated calls to `time()` always return the same value. Does the system time actually progress on Arduinos or do I need to continue querying the RTC every time I need the time?

To illustrate:

```
void InitRTC(void) {
    DateTime rtcDT;  // type defined by the RTC library
    time_t bin_time;

    rtcDT = rtc.now();
    bin_time = rtcDT.secondstime();  // returns unixlike time 
    set_system_time(bin_time);       //AVR call to set the sys time
}

void Dump(time_t t) {
    char debug_log_message[MAX_DEBUG_LENGTH];
    sprintf(debug_log_message, "    time_t:\t %lu", t);
    DebugLog(debug_log_message); //....routine to print to the serial port
}

void setup() {
    InitRTC();
    time_t now;
    while (1) {
        now = time(0);
        Dump(now);
    }
}
```

(safety checks omitted, serial code omitted).

This simply prints the same time for ever - it never progresses!

Comment: C != C++. Tag only with the language that you're using, unless both are actually relevant.

Comment: Its actually a hybrid of c and C++. DateTime is a C++ class per line of code: rtcDT.secondstime();

Comment: Your code is in *either* C or C++. There exists no C/C++ nor a hybrid of them. Always tag with the language that you're compiling your code as (which seems to be C++).

Comment: It cant really be described as anything other than a hybrid. Although the syntax does support C++ (which also implies c), the arduino chipset (Atmel) and the corresponding AVR libraries do not include the standard C++ library functions. See http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrlibcreferencemanual/FAQ_1faq_cplusplus.html It does however support the standard C library (albeit modified). see: http://nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/ Furthermore, my dev environment uses the C/C++ managed build settings under Eclipse CDT. So I'll stand by "hybrid".

Comment: @BrendanMcL : The Arduino Sketch development environment uses GCC C++ compilation, therefore it is C++ (even if that code is also valid C).  Not including the C++ library does not make it _not_ C++ - the language and the library are independent as they are in C.  You could avoid the controversy and language lawyer pedantry by omitting both C and C++ - Arduino on its own is probably sufficient.  Using the procedural rather then OO paradigm in C++ does not make the code C either.

Comment: @Clifford : thanks for the wise advice and very correct points. This is my second (and potentially last attempt) at engaging with this platform to little avail. You seem to be a highly experienced embedded programmer. Any hint on an answer to the substance of my question?

Comment: the logic/hardware is going to be simply a timer, but this timers goal is to tell time so it may sort out hours minutes seconds for you so you dont have to do the math, might have an alarm, etc.  Like any timer you need to initialize it and start it and it should then free-run and be ready to sample whenever, so if you need the time you are naturally going to need to sample it.  You are using libraries that are many layers removed from the logic.  Did you start with a very simple rtc example from somewhere? by itself without other peripherals?  If not I would.

Comment: You're both wrong - policy is quite explicit that tags are to be used for what a question is *about* not what it *contains*.  If you want syntax highlighting so badly, use the proper notations for that, don't mis-tag it with a language irrelevant to the actual question and thereby pollute the language tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library has few platform dependencies, so is very portable.  However one of those dependencies is the source for real-time, which is entirely platform dependent, and as such it is common for libraries to leave the function as a stub to be re-defined by the user to suit the specific platform or to implement hook functions or call-backs to run the standard library clock.

With the avr-libc used by AVR based Arduino platformsfFor `time()` to advance it is necessary to call the hook function `system_tick()` at 1 second intervals (typically from a timer or RTC interrupt)  (refer to the [avr-libc time.h documentation](http://nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__time.html#ga26c7d1dbf93fa8c23c5effbacec91f8c).  It is also necessary to set the time at initialisation using the `set_system_time()` function.

Invoking `system_tick()` from a 1Hz timer will then maintain `time()`, but it is also possible to use an RTC alarm interrupt, by advancing the alarm match target on each interrupt. So you might for example have:

```
void rtc_interrupt()
{
    // Set next interrupt for 1 seconds time.
    RTC rtc ;
    int next = rtc.getSeconds() + 1 ;
    if( next == 60 )
    {
        next = 0 ;
    }
    rtc.setAlarmSeconds( next ) ;

    // update std time
    system_tick() ;
}

void init_system_time()
{
    tm component_time ;
    RTC rtc ;

    // Get *consistent* time components - i.e ensure the 
    // components are not read either side of a minute boundary
    do
    {
        component_time.tm_sec = rtc.getSeconds() ;
        component_time.tm_min = rtc.getMInutes(),
        component_time.tm_hour = rtc.getHours(),
        component_time.tm_mday = rtc.getDay(),
        component_time.tm_mon = rtc.getMonth() - 1,  // January = 0 in struct tm
        component_time.tm_year = rtc.getYear() + 100  // Years since 1900 

    } while( component_time.tm_min != rtc.getMinutes() ) ;

    set_system_time( mktime( &component_time ) - UNIX_OFFSET ) ;

    // Set alarm for now + one second
    rtc.attachInterrupt( rtc_interrupt ) ;
    rtc.setAlarmSeconds( rtc.getSeconds() + 1 ) ;
    rtc.enableAlarm( rtc.MATCH_SS ) ;
}
```

An alternative is to override `time()` completely and read the RTC directly on each call - this has the advantage of not requiring any interrupt handlers for example:

```
#include <time.h>
extern "C" time_t time( time_t* time )
{
    tm component_time ;
    RTC rtc ;
    // Get *consistent* time components - i.e ensure the 
    // components are not read either side of a minute boundary
    do
    {
        component_time.tm_sec = rtc.getSeconds() ;
        component_time.tm_min = rtc.getMInutes(),
        component_time.tm_hour = rtc.getHours(),
        component_time.tm_mday = rtc.getDay(),
        component_time.tm_mon = rtc.getMonth() - 1,  // January = 0 in struct tm
        component_time.tm_year = rtc.getYear() + 100  // Years since 1900 

    } while( component_time.tm_min != rtc.getMinutes() ) ;

    return mktime( &component_time ) ;
}
```

I have assumed that the Arduino library `getYear()` returns years since 2000, and that `getMonth()` returns 1-12, but neither is documented, so modify as necessary.

Linking the above function *before* linking libc will cause the library version to be overridden.

Comment: You are correct on the platform dependency. I'm using GCC on linux to build and it links against avr-libc (see http://nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/modules.html). So I have both time_t and tm structs (and localtime, mktime etc). And you are correct in that the time_t epoch reference is 2000. However, my question is in regard system time (as returned by time() as a time_t - it doesn't progress. ie. tick, move forward. Its seems to be static - can be set and read using standard library functions but it doesn't actually tick forward in time!

Comment: My point stands.  It will not advance if it has not been implemented!  If the RTC functions are implemented and work, the above will work.  time() is likely implemented as a "weak link" stub so that code using it will link, though not necessarily work.  The library cannot magically know the source for system time - you have to tell it by implementing the necessary system level functions.

Comment: @BrendanMcL :  I took the trouble to read the avr-libc documentation and have updated my answer.  My original suggestion however remains the better solution IMO as it has not interrupt handler overhead.

Comment: My original method of reading the RTC was flawed, because it was possible for the time to tick over a minute mid-way through reading the individual components, causing the time to appear to jump by 59 seconds.  Fixed.

Comment: Note also the above was determined from the documentation, not from actual implementation - may contain flaws or need some rework.

Comment: thanks heaps for your answer - makes complete sense. Although the library implements <time.h> it never occurred to be that it wouldn't tick by itself - which of course makes sense on the arduino platform because there is no OS services to take care of such matters! I ended up using your last suggestion (initially as my own TimeNow() function) with directives to either use time() or rtc.() depending on the target - AVR or linux. Again, many thanks.

Comment: @BrendanMcL :  That's a reasonable solution unless you are using third party code that you'd rather not modify, in which case overriding the library `time()` makes sense.  That said in the tiny amount of code you  can get into an AVR based Arduino, I doubt that it is much of an advantage.

Comment: indeed! I’m well and truly over Arduino. Though I haven’t written code in earnest for 25 odd years (thus my leaning to ANSI), the ease of use on the Arduino was compelling (and my boys are learning it at school too). Thinking the best way to get up to speed was to just jump in, a hobby project has now taken on a potentially serious commercial slant. With 8k of ram and as much as possible already shoved into PROGMEM I’ve spent weeks fighting with memory constraints. Can I send you a personal message on this platform?

Comment: @BrendanMcL : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261885/should-we-be-able-to-send-private-messages-to-other-users  I am not that hard to find by other means, but asking questions of SO is likely more productive if you follow the rules and guidelines.